# Android soft touch keyboard

Tags: java, android, oop, user-interface, keyboard

I'm new to programming with Android and am trying to figure out how to get the soft touch keyboard to appear when an EditText item is clicked in, (when the activity loads there is only one user input field, so it stays in focus) so far I have the below method I made however when it shows the keyboard, the keyboard cannot be closed by the user... the button to close the keyboard is there however it does not hide it.

```
public void showKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager myKeyboard = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context
        .INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    myKeyboard.showSoftInput(PN_input,InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

Any help or point in the right direction would be helpful :)

Edit: Hide keyboard method I'm using when the find button is clicked

```
public void hideKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager myKeyboard = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    myKeyboard.hideSoftInputFromWindow(PN_input.getWindowToken(),0);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell how you want to hide softkey

Comment: Added to question above

Answer (score 0):

Put this to your Activity onCreate  to hide softkey when Activity starts below code hides your softkey.

```
 this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);// for hide keypad
```

When you touch on EditText, automatically softkey will appears, No need of Code for do this, for hiding softkey touch anywhere inside the screen.

For **Show KeyPad** use this code :

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                                 getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if(imm != null){
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
    }
```

For **Hide Keypad** use this code :

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                                  getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if(imm != null){
        imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
```

Comment: If you will get any issue , please comment

Comment: I don't need to hide the keyboard at onCreate, that's when I need the keyboard to be visible. When the user clicks search it hides the keyboard and shows the results from the search below the EditText widget. When a user then clicks the EditText again, it shows the keyboard again, however the 'hide keyboard' button on the soft touch keyboard doesn't function to hide it. You can click it but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

From digging in the android developer website, I was able to create a method that works to show the keyboard and the 'done' button works to close the keyboard.

```
    InputMethodManager myKeyboard = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    myKeyboard.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html